# Enable interaction with a chart (zoom in/out) MPAndroidChart on Android

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart on Android

When there are 11 data, only 9 are displayed on the screen.

I want to move the screen by dragging to see the rest, but it is impossible.

Need to add something?

```
chart.setData(data);

XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
chart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);

chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

chart.setScaleEnabled(false);


CustomMarkerView marker = new CustomMarkerView(getContext(),R.layout.chart_marker);
chart.setMarkerView(marker);

xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);

xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(90f);

xAxis.setLabelCount(mWeekDataset.size(),false);
xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your problem. You have to set `chart.setScaleEnabled(true);`, not `false`.

From documentation:

```
/**
     * Set this to true to enable scaling (zooming in and out by gesture) for
     * the chart (this does not effect dragging) on both X- and Y-Axis.
     *
     * @param enabled
     */
    public void setScaleEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.mScaleXEnabled = enabled;
        this.mScaleYEnabled = enabled;
    }
```